# Save the path of a picture on shared preferences

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, sharedpreferences, filenotfoundexception

On my code, users can select a "profile picture"
Users select the picture from gallery (ok work) resize and crop (ok work)
i have a problem to share the path of the picture, because i have to see that picture in other activity
i thing to save the full path on a shared preferences, but i have an error of "file not found", but the patch is correct.

Sorry for the english
 there is the full code: (when i open again this activity, i have the error)

```
public class profilo extends Activity{

    String nickname;
    EditText nick;
    ImageView prof;
    ImageButton elisse;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
     private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        //codici relativi alla action bar
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("Impostazioni utente");
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.back);
        //________________________________


        updatePreferencesData();

    ImageButton Foto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    Button salva = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSalva);
    Button password = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    elisse= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Switch facebook = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    nick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    nickname = "temp";
    prof= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    View.OnClickListener gestore = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {  

            switch(view.getId()){

              case R.id.imageButton1: //imposta foto profilo
                  Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                  break;

              case R.id.buttonSalva: //salva il nickname e le altre impostazioni
                 nickname = nick.getText().toString();
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Salvataggio non implementato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("il nick name è " +nickname);

                 break;

              case R.id.button1:
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditPassword.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
                  break;

              case R.id.imageView1:  //setto al click anche sulla foto del profilo, l'apertura della gallery (o lo zoom?? )
                  Intent b = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(b, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                  break;

            }
          }

        };

        Foto.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        salva.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        password.setOnClickListener(gestore);
        elisse.setOnClickListener(gestore);
}


    //gestisco la grafica della barra

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
              mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.barra_home, menu);

              return true;
      }

    //gestisco i click sulla barra in alto
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuLoggato.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
           /* case R.id.abForwardHoloLight:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
                    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    return true; */
            default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }
    }


    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();

             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             cursor.close();
              // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image


             //qui dovrei mandare l'immagine a saverio e poi ritagliarla


          SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferenze", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         // EditText outputView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputData);
          CharSequence textData = picturePath;

          if (textData != null) {
              editor.putString("path", ""+textData);
             editor.commit();
          }
          //aggiorno le preferenze e prendo la foto
          updatePreferencesData();

         }
     }

    //metodo per tagliare l'immagine
    public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
         int minore = 0;
            //devo trovare il minore fra larghezza ed altezza e setto il raggio con quello
            if( bitmap.getWidth()<=bitmap.getHeight()){
                minore = bitmap.getWidth();
            }else{
                minore = bitmap.getHeight();
            }
         Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(minore, minore, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        //final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, minore, minore);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(minore / 2, minore / 2,  minore / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
        //return _bmp;
        return output;
    }

    private void updatePreferencesData(){
        // Leggiamo le Preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Preferenze", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Leggiamo l'informazione associata alla proprietà TEXT_DATA
        String textData = prefs.getString("path", "NO");

        System.out.println("path:" + textData);
        if(textData.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")==false){
      try{  Bitmap profilo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(textData);
          profilo = getCroppedBitmap(profilo);
          prof.setImageBitmap(profilo);
          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("errore " +e);
          }

            }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Modifica la foto con un click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I don't think we need full code here. Extract relevant parts.

Comment: could you please send an example of your path or the logcat error? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS FUNCTION IN KEEP IN YOUR UTILITY CLASS TO GET THE IMAGE PATH AS STRING

*** Don't close the cursor**

```
public static String getImgPathFromGallary(final Context context,Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = ((Activity) context).managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

and call like

```
@Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             Uri imguri= data.getData();
             String imgPath= YourUtilityClass.getImgPathFromGallary(this,imguri);
             SharedPreferences settings = activity.getSharedPreferences("Preferenze", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("path", imgPath);
        editor.commit();

      }
    }
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
public void getpic(){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "select pic"), gallerycode );
    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==gallerycode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri picaddr = data.getData();
        String selectedpath = getpath(picaddr);
        File f = new File(selectedpath);
        String abspath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        editor.putString("imageaddr",abspath );

        editor.commit();
    }

private String getpath(Uri picaddr) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(picaddr, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

i am saving the absolute path of the image to shared preferences in onActivityResult().

Comment: doesnt' work... 

05-30 08:14:49.533: I/System.out(3476): path:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130530_075625.jpg 
05-30 08:14:49.763: I/System.out(3476): Exceptions java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: managedQuery is deprecated is instead Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(picaddr, projection, null, null, null);

Comment: The path must begin like this: /storage/sdcard0

Comment: and how i can write the path like yours? adding the string? like /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/img... ??

Comment: the path is changed to the way jarvis wrote from jellybean onwards.you wont get that in the previous versions..

Comment: but if i take the picture in a device with jb, i have the new path, else if i take the picture from a device with ics i have the old path. In both case i have the error for "file not found"
It's possibile tu insert reading permision on the activity?